# How to compare two RGB images in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I need to compare two color RBG images and get a result images of difference pixel by pixel. Is there any idea how can I do that in qt ?

I would appreciate for any help or advice.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do... I know that interpolationin RGB-space is usually poor. I'm not sure how the difference would work. I'd be tempted to convert it to HSV-space and do some sort of subtraction or correlation there. I'm not too familiar with that area, but you might want to look through the OpenCV docs and see if they already have a tool that solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative based on this [QtForum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/39871/how-to-compare-two-images-properly/2) question:

```
void substract(const QImage &left, const QImage &rigth, QImage &result)
{
  int w=min(left.width(), rigth.width());
  int h=min(left.height(),rigth.height();
  w=min(w, result.width());
  h=min(h, result.height();
  //<-This ensures that you work only at the intersection of images areas

  for(int i=0;i<h;i++){
    QRgb *rgbLeft=(QRgb*)left.constScanLine(i);
    QRgb *rgbRigth=(QRgb*)rigth.constScanLine(i);
    QRgb *rgbResult=(QRgb*)result.constScanLine(i);
    for(int j=0;j<w;j++){
        rgbResult[j] = rgbLeft[j]-rgbRigth[j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this code is correct in terms of determining "color difference" - it merely finds the difference between two ints that are used to store color information. Thus if you calculate the difference between a red pixel and a blue pixel, it will give you a red result, when the actual color difference between red and green is yellow.

Comment: @dtech, good point, but it depends on what are you going to do with the `result` image. You can think about and RGB color as a 3D  vector of ints, and this difference is the vector that goes from `rgbLeft` to `rgbRigth` in a 3D representation of the RGB space.

Answer (score 0):

First, an RGB image is a 3-dimensional matrix containing the 3 channels (R,G,B)

To achieve the difference you can simply subtract the matrixes.

If you're using OpenCv consider the code below, otherwise you can traverse the matrixes and subtract each position separately.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

Mat img = imread("...");
Mat img2 = imread("...");

Mat diff_img = img - img2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `QImage` you can iterate on pixel level, and simply output the RBG differences into a third image.

```
QRgb QImage::pixel(int x, int y) const
void QImage::setPixelColor(int x, int y, const QColor &color)
```

Keep in mind to iterate row sequentially for optimal performance. Meaning that the row should be your inner loop. A lot of the time people instinctively do the opposite, probably because most people prioritize width over height, therefore putting the row as the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

> This is how you can compare two same size(height and width) images. You also can use some STD functionality instead of this trivial code. This is just to show how it should going

```
// 'first' and 'second' it's  QImage objects 
int AbsoluteError = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < first.height(); ++y)
{
    QRgb *line1 = reinterpret_cast<QRgb*>(first.scanLine(y));
    QRgb *line2 = reinterpret_cast<QRgb*>(second.scanLine(y));
    for (int x = 0; x < first.width(); ++x)
    {
        QRgb &rgb1 = line1[x];
        int A1 = qAlpha(rgb1);
        int R1 = qRed(rgb1);
        int G1 = qGreen(rgb1);
        int B1 = qBlue(rgb1);

        QRgb &rgb2 = line2[x];
        int A2 = qAlpha(rgb2);
        int R2 = qRed(rgb2);
        int G2 = qGreen(rgb2);
        int B2 = qBlue(rgb2);

        bool A = A1 == A2;
        bool R = R1 == R2;
        bool G = G1 == G2;
        bool B = B1 == B2;

        if(!A || !R || !G || !B)
        {
            rgb2 = qRgba(qRed(rgb2), qGreen(0), qBlue(rgb2), qAlpha(rgb2)); //made a mark on img where the difference
            ++AbsoluteError;
        }
    }
}


ui->LineEdit1->setText(QString::number(AbsoluteError));
ui->LineEdit2->setText(QString::number((AbsoluteError*100)/(width1*height1))); //absolute error in %
```

Answer (score -1):

bool ImagesAreSimilar(QImage *img1,QImage *img2)
{

```
if (img1->isNull()||img2->isNull())
{
  return false ;
}
if (img1->height()!=img2->height()) {
    return false ;
}
if (img1->width()!=img2->width()) {
    return false ;
}
 auto pixel1 = img1->bits();
 auto pixel2 = img2->bits();
 bool similar=true;
for (int y = 0; y < img1->height(); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img1->width(); x++)
    {

        if (    (pixel1[0]!=pixel2[0])||
                (pixel1[1]!=pixel2[1])||
                (pixel1[2]!=pixel2[2])||
                (pixel1[3]!=pixel2[3])) {
                return false ;
        }
        pixel1  += 4;
        pixel2 += 4;
    }
}
```

return similar;

}